# Difference in symmetries of Second quantized and First quantized Hamiltonian

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, time-reversal-symmetry, charge-conjugation

The following is stated in (among others) the articles

- *[Topological insulators and superconductors: ten-fold way and dimensional hierarchy](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.2157)* - Shinsei Ryu, Andreas Schnyder, Akira Furusaki, Andreas Ludwig
- *[Classification of topological quantum matter with symmetries](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.03535)* - Ching-Kai Chiu, Jeffrey C.Y. Teo, Andreas P. Schnyder, Shinsei Ryu

The three discrete symmetries Time reversal symmetry ($T$), Particle-hole symmetry ($C$) and Chiral symmetry ($S$) all commute (are real symmetries) of the full second quantized Hamiltonian,
$$\hat{H}=\sum_{A,B}\Psi_A^\dagger \mathcal{H}_{AB}\Psi_B. $$
That is,
$$[\hat{T},\hat{H}]=[\hat{C},\hat{H}]=[\hat{S},\hat{H}]=0.\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (1)$$
They go on to claim that, $\hat{C}$ and $\hat{S}$ are not real symmetries in the "classical" sense of the first quantized Hamiltonian $\mathcal{H}$. In fact, the first quantized Hamiltonians obey,

$$[T,\mathcal{H}]=\{C,\mathcal{H}\}=\{S,\mathcal{H}\}=0. \;\;\;\;\;\; (2)$$
**How can I prove that imposing Eq. (1) implies Eq. (2)?**

Comment: You can find the proof of most cases in my answer of the following question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/381328/why-particle-hole-symmetry-and-chiral-symmetry-are-called-symmetries/381347#381347

Comment: @DavidBarMoshe Yes! Thank you. That is the answer that I have been looking for!